# Font Size Conflict at Classes

Tags: css

I have conflict with Font Size on my Website. The Font Size is set to 0.85em at Body Class like below.

Another Class which I set 0.9em is smaller than my Standard Font Size. I dont know how it comes.

```
html {
   font-size: 100%;
} 

body, html {
   height: 100%;
}
body{
    font: normal 0.85em/1.3 Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
```

Class with bigger Font Size

```
.styled_view li.gallery .price .pricetext {
    color: #404040;
    font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    font-weight: 700 !important;
    letter-spacing: -0.02em;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [MDN page for font-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size) has a good explanation of `em`:

> When defining the font-size property, an em is equal to the size of the font that applies to the parent of the element in question.

So your `.95em` is based on the parent font size, which you've set. Since your font size is a decimal, it will be smaller than the parent.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Means to set the font-size for classes which is needed.